# Modelmapper in java generic object

Tags: java, generics, dto, modelmapper

My goal is to map an entity to a dto object. Suppose we have these classes:

```
class GenericPaging<T> {
 private List<T> list;
}
class Cat{
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private Cat parent;
}
class CatDTO{
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private int parentId;
}
```

In fact, I want to map `cat` to `catDTO`. For simple mapping it works. Example similar to this:

```
 catDTO = modelmapper.map(cat,CatDTO.class);
```

but for complex objects, it does not work. For example:

```
   Cat cat1 = new Cat(1, "Cat1", null);
   Cat cat2 = new Cat(2, "Cat2", cat1);
   Cat cat3 = new Cat(3, "Cat3", cat1);
   List<Cat> cats = Arrays.asList(cat1, cat2, cat3);

   GenericPaging<Cat> pagingCat = new GenericPaging();
   pagingCat.setList(cats);
```

Now for mapping, I used this command:

```
 modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Cat, CatDTO>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map().setParentId(source.getParent().getId());
        }
    });
pagingCatDTO=modelMapper.map(pagingCat,new TypeToken<GenericPaging<CatDTO>>(){}.getType());
```

When I want to see `parentId` in dto object, it throws an exception.

```
for(CatDTO cDTO:pagingCatDTO.getList()){
   System.out.println(cDTO.getParentId());
}
```

This is the exception thrown:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Test.modelmapper.Cat cannot be cast to Test.modelmapper.CatDTO

If using separate classes for each object (cat, catDTO,) it works correctly.
Like this:

```
 class PagingCat{
   private List<Cat> list;
 }

 class PagingCatDTO{
    private List<CatDTO> list;
  }
```

I think the problem is caused by generic class. i.e `GenericPaging<T>`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: "What is my problem [...]?" => That is something you should tell us. We can give you a solution iff we get a proper problem description. As it is, this question is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, @Joe C please see updated question. i want to have CatDTO objects. i.e `id`,`name` and `parentId` but display `Cat` fields.

Comment: This question is a good bit more readable now.  It was hard to parse all that being said.